# Display immediate parent after CONNECT_BY_ROOT in Oracle PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, connect-by

I am using oracle 12 DB and client. Need help on this one. I want to populate a column which displays the root, child, and immediate parent after the root? lets say "CONNECT BY 2nd ROOT"?

Here is my code so far.

```
SELECT
          PARENT,
          CONNECT_BY_ROOT PARENT_ID AS ROOT_ID,
      ????2ND_ROOT_ID,
          CHILD_ID AS CHILD_ID 
     FROM TABLE
     START WITH 
        PARENT_ID = 1 
     CONNECT BY
         PRIOR CHILD_ID =  PARENT_ID
```

INPUT

```
PARENT_ID   CHILD_ID
1           1.1
1           1.2
1.1         1.1.1
1.1         1.1.2
1.1         1.1.3
1.1         1.1.4
1.1         1.1.5
1.2         1.2.1
1.2         1.2.2
1.1.1       1.1.1.1
1.1.1       1.1.1.2
1.1.3       1.1.3.1
1.1.3       1.1.3.2
1.1.3       1.1.3.3
```

OUTPUT:

```
ROOT_ID  2ND_ROOT_ID    CHILD_ID
    1        1.1        1.1
    1        1.2        1.2
    1        1.1        1.1.1
    1        1.1        1.1.2
    1        1.1        1.1.3
    1        1.1        1.1.4
    1        1.1        1.1.5
    1        1.2        1.2.1
    1        1.2        1.2.2
    1        1.1        1.1.1.1
    1        1.1        1.1.1.2
    1        1.1        1.1.3.1
    1        1.1        1.1.3.2
    1        1.1        1.1.3.3
```

Also tried using substring from connect by path

```
regexp_substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH, ....
```

To get the parent after the root  but it gives me a ORA-01489 error.

Kindly advice and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional sys_connect_by_path:

```sql
rtrim(sys_connect_by_path(case when level<=2 then id else null end, '.'),'.')
```

Comment: hi Sayan, If i try using sys_connect_by_path in combination with rtrim or substr  ORA-01489 appears... Also tried using TO_CLOB to prevent  the error but it keeps showing up

Comment: @user1215811 that's very very strange. Show us a sample of your data, please

Comment: Hi Sayan, I correct my previous comment. Just ran a wrong SQL that's why Ora-01489 appeared. 
And Yes, your conditional sys_connect_by_path: worked. This is the one I need. Many many thanks. Appreciate it sir.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using LEVEL keyword. LEVEL shows the position or level each record is at in the hierarchy with respect to the root. So in the classic EMPLOYEE table, if an employee Jake has this hierarchy:

Jake -> Jake's Manager -> VP -> CEO

then Jake is at LEVEL 1, the Manager is at LEVEL 2, VP at LEVEL 3, CEO at LEVEL 4.

*What you're asking for is to simply pick all LEVEL 4, 3 AND 1 records* which will give you the root, 2nd root and the record itself. But there's a problem - *LEVEL numbering start from the bottom, not from the top*. So you don't know what level the root is at for a given employee. It can be 2, 3, 4, 5 or any number based on how many levels there are in the hierarchy.

In Oracle, CONNECT_BY_ROOT gives root record but getting 2nd root isn't straightforward.

This is why the below query uses *ROW_NUMBER() analytic function to revert the order of levels* so that root becomes LEVEL 1, 2nd root becomes LEVEL 2 and so on. If root is always at LEVEL 1 and root's immediate child is always LEVEL 2, it then becomes easy to write a WHERE clause against those two.

When you use CONNECT BY like this there's a separate record for each relationship. In the WITH clause below, employee Jake will have as many records as he has managers going up to CEO. So Jake -> Jake's manager has a record. Jake -> Jake's Manager->VP has a record.. and so on, all those records belonging to employee Jake.

The EMP WITH clause below assigns incremental row numbers to each of those relationship records starting with 1 for the root, using ROW_NUMBER(). For the next employee, it again starts from 1.

EMP_PIVOT creates a new column by pivoting the manager name using ROW_NUMBER() calculation from previous step.

```
WITH EMP AS
(
SELECT E.employee_id, E.employee_name, E.designation, 
CONNECT_BY_ROOT E.employee_name as Manager_name, 
CONNECT_BY_ROOT E.designation as Manager_Designation, 
LEVEL EMP_LEVEL,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) LEVEL_HIERARCHY
FROM Employee E
CONNECT BY PRIOR E.employee_id = E.manager_id
ORDER BY 1
),
EMP_PIVOT AS
(
SELECT
MAX(DECODE(EMP.LEVEL_HIERARCHY,1,EMP.MANAGER_NAME, NULL)) OVER(PARTITION BY EMPLOYEE_ID) AS ROOT_MGR,
EMP.MANAGER_NAME AS SECOND_ROOT_MGR, 
EMP.EMPLOYEE_NAME,
LEVEL_HIERARCHY
FROM EMP 
WHERE EMP.LEVEL_HIERARCHY <=2 )

SELECT * FROM EMP_PIVOT WHERE LEVEL_HIERARCHY=2;
```

Output:

[image]

The last WHERE condition is set to LEVEL_HIERARCHY=2 so we fetch only that one record per employee which has all 3 columns we need.